# Use a for loop to plot the same period multiple times

Tags: pandas, for-loop, matplotlib, plot

I have a pandas data frame with a DateTime series:

[image: ndas][image]

And I would like to plot multiple subplots with the same x-axis (hours 0 to 23) to compare the number of users on different days.
So, in the end, I have the same number of plots as days instead of just one plot comprising all January.

I have created 2 new columns "Day" and "Hour" and tried to iterate through them as follows:

```py
for d in high['Day'].unique():
    print('Day ' + str(d))
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(high['Hour'], high['Usuarios'])
    plt.show()
```

Although I'm creating a plot per day it is not working as expected:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The main thing that is missing, is restricting the hours plotted to only one day. One way to do so is creating a new dataframe like this: `day_high = high[high['Day'] == d]`. [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/tutorials.html) supports many other ways to do so, for example [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).

Here is some sample code to show how it could work. I added a line to save the plot to a file.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import random

data = [[d, h, random.randint(0, 15)] for h in range(0, 24) for d in range(1, 32)]
high = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Day', 'Hour', 'Usuarios' ])
for d in high['Day'].unique():
    print('Day ' + str(d))
    day_high = high[high['Day'] == d]
    plt.plot(day_high ['Hour'], day_high ['Usuarios'])
    plt.title(f'Día {d}')
    plt.savefig(f'Día {d}.png')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Did this answer help you?